# Will a modern compiler automatically optimize the following C++ code?

Tags: c++, if-statement, g++

If i use hte following codes , will the compiler optimize it like a switch structure , which uses a binary tree to search for values ?

```
   if ( X == "aaaa" || X == "bbbb" || X == "cccc" || X == "dddd" )
   {

   }
   else if ( X == "abcd" || X == "cdef" || X == "qqqq" )
   {

   }
```

It's just an example , there's no pattern of what's inside the quote symbol

**UPDATE**

Ok , X is a string , but i don't really think it matters here , i just want to know , when everything inside the `if` was all about single variable , will it be optimized.

Comment: What's `X`? Some string class with custom `operator==` or a (possibly `const`) `char *`?

Comment: @Aaron I dunno :-) While I'd be skeptical as long as `std::string`s with overloaded `operator==` are concerned, I'd probably expect some cool optimisations when comparing simple types like this.

Comment: Re: your edit: It does matter! What if the `operator==` in question looks at some random numbers or does logging or throws?

Comment: There are 3 different answers, depending on whether X is a C++ object, or a constant pointer, or a non-constant pointer. It also matters if it is C++ or C, C has no copy constructors nor overloaded operators. Why did you tag this as C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values WILL be compared one after the other as it is a requirement of the `||` or, the short-circuit operator. So, here two things will happen:

- X will be compared one-by-one from right-to-left.
- There will be NO MORE comparisons after any comparison that succeeds (Since it is the short-circuit OR operator) i.e. in the following case

For example:

```
int hello() {
    std::cout<<"Hello";
    return 10;
}

int world() {
    std::cout<<"World";
    return 11;
}

int hello2() {
    std::cout<<"Hello2";
    return 9;
}

int a = 10;

bool dec = (a == hello() || a == world())
bool dec = (a == hello2() || a == hello() || a == world())
```

The output for the first statement will be:

```
Hello
```

as `a == world()` will not be executed, and for the second `Hello2 Hello`, as the comparisons keep on happening till the first success.

In case of the `&&` operator, the comparisons keep on happening until the first failure (as that is enough to determine the outcome of the entire statement).

Comment: Short-circuiting is only relevant if the comparisons have observable behavior. If you can't tell the difference in how the compiler implements it, it's fair game. (Obviously OP could be using some strange string class that has observable comparisons, but likely not.)

Comment: @GMan: The OP is interested in optimization, so he is also interested in whatever is only 'observable' if you benchmark it, or something.

Answer (score 1):

It probably depends on the flags you set. Binary trees are faster for search but usually require more code to be handled. So if you optimized for size it probably wont. I'm not sure if it will do it anyway. You know, gcc is optimized according to a LOT of flags. O1, O2, O3, O4 are just simple forms to indicate big groups of flags. You can find a list of all the optimization flags here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

Try to search for strings, binary trees, etc in that page.

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly not.  Binary search requires some sort of ordering
relationship, and an ability to compare for less-than.  The compiler
cannot assume such exists, and even if it does find one, it cannot
assume that it defines an equivalence relation which corresponds to
`==`.  It's also possible that the compiler can't determine that the
function defining the ordering relationship has no side effects.  (If it
has side effects, or if any operation in the expression has side
effects, the compiler must respect the short circuiting behavior of
`||`.)  Finally, even if the compiler did all this... what happens if I
carefully chose the order of the comparisons so that the most frequent
case is the first.  Such an “optimization” could even end up 
being a pessimization.

The “correct” to handle this is to create a map, mapping the
strings to pointers to functions (or to polymorphic functional objects,
if some state is involved).

Answer (score 0):

Best way to test this is the example like below.

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
if(a == a || b++) {
    ...
}
cout << b;
```

value of the `b` variable should be `0` at the end. `b++` part won't be executed. that's the expected behaviour but there might be some exceptions depending on the compiler and its optimization settings. even many scripting langauges like `JavaScript` behaves this way.